# Java - How to refresh knowledge? (2 years ago)

Tags: java, oop

I have my first ever interview for a Java developer role, specifically RMI, Serverlets and JDBC.

However, it has been a while (2 years) since I have done any Java coding. I am sure I still have it up there somewhere and I do remember the Java syntax

I wanted to ask how can I re-fresh everything in 2-3 days specially the OOP concepts (polymorphism, inheritance) specifically to Java?

Any links, references and tutorials appreciated.

I am new to this site and I see there is a preference for programming related questions, hope I can get away with this!

Would also appreciate those that know any Java interview questions so I can go through them and test myself.

Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest you you test yourself, e.g. on [Java Black Belt](http://www.javablackbelt.com/Home.wwa), which has a good question base grouped by categories and detailled explanations for your mistakes.

I'd also recommend (re-)reading [Sun's Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) and (longer) [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/) by Bruce Eckel (3rd edition is free to download).

Comment: Java Black Belt is no longer exist.

Answer (score 4):

[Tutorials on RMI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

[Java Servlet Technology](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html)

[JDBC Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

OOP concepts (polymorphism, inheritance): [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/)

[Java Interview Questions](http://www.allapplabs.com/interview_questions/java_interview_questions.htm)

Comment: Loved the interview questions, it's this the sort of thing I need.

Answer (score 2):

How about this. Take a certification guide. It will save you a lot of time, and give you an exercise after every chapter (might give you some interview questions). You don't need to bore you down to death by teaching yourself in a wordy way, what you might already know. The best would he Khalid's [Java Certification Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321556054). Believe me it would be faster and more effective. Plus give you the skills for appearing in the test for real, if you like to. :)